# Windows 10 1803 with USB Bluetooth Dongle = Bluescreen

Tags: windows-10, usb, bsod, bluetooth, windows-10-v1803

Using any USB 2.0 Bluetooth dongle under Windows 10 1803 results in a Bluescreen of Death (BSoD) when turning off Bluetooth or pairing (rarer). This BSoD was replicated on 8 different systems with 6 different dongles. Systems running Windows 10 1703 or 1709, Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 are not affected. 32bit Systems where not tested.

This can also happen when pairing a device with Windows Bluetooth but is less likely. Calling the pairing function via API also raises the BSoD but not every time.

This is the Bluescreen message:

> DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL 0x000000d1 (0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000, 0xfffff80583731a0d)

WinDbg message:

> Probably caused by : bthport.sys ( bthport!HCI_WriteScanEnableCallback+a4 )

Video demonstration (53 seconds, no audio)

> https://youtu.be/--yqbiCRilg

Fresh Minidumps

> https://mega.nz/#F!mWpWCAiD!ZhqDoQYD0cQXT2O7Q-vtsw
>
> (Dumps will be removed when this issue has been resolved)

The Bluetooth dongle uses the Windows included driver. Onboard Bluetooth adapters are not affected. It does not matter if the system was upgraded from 1709 or freshly installed from a 1803 ISO. Windows 10 Pro and Enterprise have been tested to produce this error.

The dongles are USB 2.0 and use Bluetooth 2.0 or 2.1 Class II.

The problem is not that the turning off of the Bluetooth Adapter produces the BSoD but that also pairing throws it.

It seems this an error introduced in Windows 10 1803. Is there a workaround or fix? Anything else I can try?

**Update 2018-07-16:** With Windows 10 Update 2018-07 (Build 17134.165) Microsoft seems to have fixed Bluetooth 2.0 adapters but broke Bluetooth 4.2 adapters now. Same error as before.

Comment: rollback to 1709 and report the issue to Microsoft via Feedback hub app. the minidumps are not that helpful. compress the C:\windows\memory.dmp and attach the zip to the error report in feedback hub app.

Comment: Submitted via Feedback hub. I cannot simply rollback as my install started of as 1803; for my other colleagues this may be a viable option.

Comment: hm, I have no idea how to fix this. Please post here the feedback share link, I'll submit it to my Microsoft contact so that they look at it faster.

Comment: Here is the link from the feedback hub: https://aka.ms/AA1et8f
I also submitted the problem via product support incident (MPN) S201805231545437388.

Comment: ok, I got the answer from Microsoft that this is a known issue and they already work an a fix and release the fix soon. So check for new Windows updates and inside WSUS block the 1803 update until the fix is available.

Comment: That is great to hear. I have been pulling my hair. Thank you for your assistance. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has addressed this issue in KB4340917 (OS Build 17134.191).

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4340917/windows-10-update-kb4340917

> Addresses issues related to peripherals that use Quality of Service (QoS) parameters for Bluetooth connections.